# MSDEPLOY Invalid Web Deploy service URL

Tags: iis, msbuild, msdeploy

I am unable to deploy to any of my servers due to a supposed problen with msdeploy. The full error messages reads

`[GenerateGlobalPublishSetting] ConcatFullServiceUrlWithSiteName
[10:54:03][ConcatFullServiceUrlWithSiteName] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3693, 5): Invalid Web Deploy service URL`

When I look at that exact line I see,

`<ConcatFullServiceUrlWithSiteName ServiceUrl="$(MsDeployServiceUrl)" SiteAppName="$(DeployIisAppPath)" 
                                      Condition="$(_UseWMSVC) And $(NormalizePublishSettings)">
      <Output TaskParameter="ResultUrl" PropertyName="MsDeployServiceUrl" />
    </ConcatFullServiceUrlWithSiteName>[GenerateGlobalPublishSetting] ConcatFullServiceUrlWithSiteName`

I have tested the msdeploy link and all relevant services appear to be working.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the way that I was passing the MSdeployserviceurl parameter. For some reason when I deployed from my local machine, I could resolve without the /msdeploy.axd. My build server apparently needed this in order to properly generate settings.

So instead of `/P:MsDeployServiceUrl=servername:8172`
it wanted  `/P:MsDeployServiceUrl=servername:8172/msdeploy.axd`